# Pegar controle de versão do Git e salvar numa constante do PHP

Tags: php, javascript, git, gulp

Existe uma forma possível de salvar dentro do código PHP o hash do GIT ou uma numeração de versão de forma automática cada vez que der push, ou por Javascript, usando o gulp, salvar a versão no PHP?

Gostaria de fazer isso para não ter que ficar colocando a versão manualmente da aplicação.

```
define('VERSION_WEBAPP', '0.6.1');
```

seria algo do tipo:

```
$git_version = 'pegaria o rash ou número do commit';

define('VERSION_WEBAPP', $git_version);
```

Comment: Um código que faz o que você procura foi dado nessa resposta : [codigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967368/execute-git-command-from-php-and-get-error-message-back)

Comment: Não é bem isso que eu preciso. @IsraelZebulon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri uma maneira legal usando gulp...

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var fs = require('fs');
var version = '1.2.3.' + (new Date()).getTime();

gulp.task('version', function(cb){
     fs.writeFile('./application/configs/version.ini', '[version]\nversion = '+version, cb);
});
```

E no PHP:

```
$version_app = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/version.ini', 'version');
$data_version = $version_app->toArray();

define('VERSION_WEBAPP', $data_version['version']);
```